# How can I set column name which is same with keyword?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How can I set Column name as 'call'?
I tried:

```
create table Reports(
  id int not null,
  state int not null,
  call varchar(255),
  primary key(id)
);
```

call with brackets [call] does not work. How Can I do it?

Comment: Fix your column name!  Don't use reserved words for identifiers.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I understand that this is not a good case, but  is it impossible?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql) more explanation. From the perspective of someone using your schema having keyword-conflicting table or column names is *extremely annoying* and should be avoided whenever possible. `[call]` is SQL Server notation, different from MySQL.

Comment: Use quoted identifiers. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html.  For mysql, this is a back-tick character.

Comment: @tadman You are right. I'm that someone who using other's schema... backtick works. Thank you